# I have eclipse with pydev and i set the background to black and text white. now when i click on any word, is highlighted in a yellow color

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I have eclipse with pydev and i set the background to black and text white. now when i click on any word, is highlighted in a yellow color and i don't know how to change this yellow color to another. please help

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Solved: Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations -> Occurrences (Pydev) and change the color :D

Comment: You saved my eyes ;D

Answer (score 1):

Window -> Preferences -> Text Editors -> Appearance color options in the bottom and change the current highlight color