# How to config Eclipse select world

Tags: eclipse

Please help me how to change this yellow background color in eclipse. Thanks you!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click > Preferences > Editor
and choose the colours
[within preferences box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdMQB.png)

Check out this thread:
[I have eclipse with pydev and i set the background to black and text white. now when i click on any word, is highlighted in a yellow color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313492/i-have-eclipse-with-pydev-and-i-set-the-background-to-black-and-text-white-now)

Comment: I can't do it. I use PYDEV on Eclipse code python.

Comment: This thread might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313492/i-have-eclipse-with-pydev-and-i-set-the-background-to-black-and-text-white-now

Answer (score 0):

This selection is on:

Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors

Then on the Appearance color options you can change the "Selection background color"